# DRF: How to prefetch a queryset for my properties?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a lot of properties on my model `Author`. Each of them uses `self.book_set`.

```
class Author(models.Model):
    #....

    @property
    def book_impressions(self):
        return self.book_set.aggregate(Sum("impressions").get("impressions__sum") or 0

    @property
    def book_reach(self):
        return self.book_set.aggregate(Sum("reach").get("reach__sum") or 0

    # more @property here...


class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    reach = models.IntegerField()
    impressions = models.IntegerField()
    # ....
```

I have a view responsible for retrieving a single `Author`. As you might imagine the database is hit very often. Where is the right point to insert my `prefetch_related`?

Comment: This will not help, since the aggregate will make an extra query, even if the queryset is prefetched, since the `.aggregates` are aggrated at database side. What you can use is `.annotate`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - so would you suggest moving the logic of the properties to the `get_queryset` method of the corresponding View?

Comment: yes, since that will make annotations in *bulk*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not help, since the aggregate will make an extra query, even if the queryset is prefetched, since the [**`.aggregate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate) are aggrated at database side. Even if you thus prefetched the related books, Django will see that you do not iterate over `.all()` and make an extra query.

What you can use is [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate):

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

Author.objects.annotate(
    impressions=Coalesce(Sum('book__impressions'), Value(0)),
    reach=Coalesce(Sum('book__reach'), Value(0))
)
```

The `Author`s that arise from *this* queryset, will have two extra attributes `.impressions` and `.reach`, that will be the sum of the `impressions` and `reach` of the related `Book` objects. The annotates are done in bulk, so Django will make a query that looks like:

```
SELECT author.*,
       COALESCE(SUM(book.impressions), 0) AS impresssions,
       COALESCE(SUM(book.reach), 0) AS impresssions
FROM author
LEFT OUTER JOIN book ON book.author_id = author.id
GROUP BY author.id
```

You thus might want to remove the properties completely, since these will indeed introduce an *N+1 problem*.